# how to join and align the two boxes

Tags: css

I take part in some online lessons for Html, css and java script. I am at the end of the third week and we have been given an exercise to make a diary. I've been training for several days and I can't do it, so far I've done that...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwruw.jpg)

the foto in the left...but we have to make the foto in the right

```css
:root {
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 --light_text: #a39d9e;
 --dark_text: #363b41;
 --active_color_dark: #ff8494;
 --active_color_light: #ffa9b7;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 width: 370px;
 height: 671px;
/* (α) Γενικά για το έγγραφο html */

 

}
.container {
 margin: 10em auto;
 width: 80.9em;
 height: ;
}
.calendar {
 width: 37em;
 height: 67em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-top:2em;
 padding-right:3em;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 padding-left: 3em;
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 color: var(--dark_text);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);

}

/* (β) Για το div .calendar */
.calendar_header{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: justify;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* (γ) Για το div .calendar_header */

.calendar_subheader{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: normal;
 content: normal;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
/* (δ) Για το div .calendar_subheader */

.calendar_plan{
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-bottom:1.5em;
 padding-top: 2em;
 padding-left:2em ;
 background: var(--active_color_light);
 color:white; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-sizing: content-box;
}
/* (ε) για το στοιχείο div .calendar_plan */

/* (στ) για τα στοιχεία που περιέχονται στο .calendar_plan */

.plus_sign{ 
 border-radius: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 11em;
 margin-bottom: 0em;;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(250, 249, 249);
    background-color: white;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
/* (ζ) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου plus_sign */
.calendar_events{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* (η) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου calendar_events */
.event_item{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* (θ) Διαμόρφωση των στοιχείων του event_item */


/* (ι) Συμπεριφορά του event_item όταν το ποντίκι υπερίπταται του στοιχείου */


/* (κ) Συμπεριφορά των επαφών */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ημερολόγιο</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
      
      <div class="calendar_header">
        <h1 class="header_title">Φεβρουάριος</h1>
        <p class="calendar_subheader">Φεβρουάριος</p>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_plan">
        <div class="day_title">Σήμερα</div>
        <div class="day_body">2 Φεβρουαρίου 2020</div>
        <div class="day_add">
          <span class="plus_sign"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_events">
        <p class="calendar_events_title">Προγραμματισμένα συμβάντα</p>
      
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot dot_active"></div><div class="event_item_title">10:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με την ομάδα σχεδίασης</div>
        </div>

        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">12:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με τον πελάτη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">13:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Διάλειμμα για φαγητό με τη <span class="contact">Μαρία</span></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">14:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Τηλεδιάσκεψη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">15:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Προθεσμία για την υποβολή της πρότασης</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the problem for me its to align the to boxes so to have the button sign....
Any help will be nice for me!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Turn `.event-item` into a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex;justify-content-end` in `.container` class or `float:right` in `.calender` class

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need to do is make the elements that you need to be aligned vertically inline elements by changing their display property and make their vertical-align property middle.

```
<div class="middle-centered">
    <div class="day_body">2 Φεβρουαρίου 2020</div>
    <div class="day_add">
      <span class="plus_sign"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

now in your css

```
.middle-centered * {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: they said to dont change html...just css

Comment: You can use calendar_plan as middle-centered I used above and to align the icon to the bottom you can use negative margin on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
:root {
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 --light_text: #a39d9e;
 --dark_text: #363b41;
 --active_color_dark: #ff8494;
 --active_color_light: #ffa9b7;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 width: 370px;
 height: 671px;
/* (α) Γενικά για το έγγραφο html */

 

}
.container {
 margin: 10em auto;
 width: 80.9em;
 height: ;
}
.calendar {
 width: 37em;
 height: 67em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-top:2em;
 padding-right:3em;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 padding-left: 3em;
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 color: var(--dark_text);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);

}

/* (β) Για το div .calendar */
.calendar_header{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: justify;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* (γ) Για το div .calendar_header */

.calendar_subheader{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: normal;
 content: normal;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
/* (δ) Για το div .calendar_subheader */

.calendar_plan{
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-bottom:1.5em;
 padding: 2em;
 background: var(--active_color_light);
 color:white; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
/* (ε) για το στοιχείο div .calendar_plan */

/* (στ) για τα στοιχεία που περιέχονται στο .calendar_plan */

.plus_sign{ 
 border-radius: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 0em;;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(250, 249, 249);
    background-color: white;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
/* (ζ) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου plus_sign */
.calendar_events{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* (η) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου calendar_events */
.event_item{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* (θ) Διαμόρφωση των στοιχείων του event_item */


/* (ι) Συμπεριφορά του event_item όταν το ποντίκι υπερίπταται του στοιχείου */


/* (κ) Συμπεριφορά των επαφών */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ημερολόγιο</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
      
      <div class="calendar_header">
        <h1 class="header_title">Φεβρουάριος</h1>
        <p class="calendar_subheader">Φεβρουάριος</p>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_plan">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="day_title">Σήμερα</div>
          <div class="day_body">2 Φεβρουαρίου 2020</div>
        </div>
        <div class="day_add">
          <span class="plus_sign"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_events">
        <p class="calendar_events_title">Προγραμματισμένα συμβάντα</p>
      
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot dot_active"></div><div class="event_item_title">10:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με την ομάδα σχεδίασης</div>
        </div>

        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">12:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με τον πελάτη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">13:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Διάλειμμα για φαγητό με τη <span class="contact">Μαρία</span></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">14:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Τηλεδιάσκεψη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">15:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Προθεσμία για την υποβολή της πρότασης</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 --light_text: #a39d9e;
 --dark_text: #363b41;
 --active_color_dark: #ff8494;
 --active_color_light: #ffa9b7;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 width: 370px;
 height: 671px;
/* (α) Γενικά για το έγγραφο html */

 

}
.container {
 margin: 10em auto;
 width: 80.9em;
 height: ;
}
.calendar {
 width: 37em;
 height: 67em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-top:2em;
 padding-right:3em;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 padding-left: 3em;
 --bg_color: #efefef;
 color: var(--dark_text);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);

}

/* (β) Για το div .calendar */
.calendar_header{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: justify;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* (γ) Για το div .calendar_header */

.calendar_subheader{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: normal;
 content: normal;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
/* (δ) Για το div .calendar_subheader */

.calendar_plan{
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-bottom:1.5em;
 padding: 1em;
 background: var(--active_color_light);
 color:white; 
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-sizing: content-box;
}
/* (ε) για το στοιχείο div .calendar_plan */

/* (στ) για τα στοιχεία που περιέχονται στο .calendar_plan */

.plus_sign{ 
 border-radius: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(250, 249, 249);
    background-color: white;
    color: silver;
    text-align: center;
}
/* (ζ) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου plus_sign */
.calendar_events{
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: var(--light_text);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* (η) διαμόρφωση του στοιχείου calendar_events */
.event_item{
 box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:20px;
}

/* (θ) Διαμόρφωση των στοιχείων του event_item */


/* (ι) Συμπεριφορά του event_item όταν το ποντίκι υπερίπταται του στοιχείου */


/* (κ) Συμπεριφορά των επαφών */
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ημερολόγιο</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calendar">
      
      <div class="calendar_header">
        <h1 class="header_title">Φεβρουάριος</h1>
        <p class="calendar_subheader">Φεβρουάριος</p>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar_plan">
        <div class="day_title">Σήμερα</div>
        <div class="day_body">2 Φεβρουαρίου 2020 <span class="plus_sign">+</span>        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="calendar_events">
        <p class="calendar_events_title">Προγραμματισμένα συμβάντα</p>
      
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot dot_active"></div><div class="event_item_title">10:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με την ομάδα σχεδίασης</div>
        </div>

        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">12:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Συνάντηση με τον πελάτη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">13:00</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Διάλειμμα για φαγητό με τη <span class="contact">Μαρία</span></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">14:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Τηλεδιάσκεψη</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="event_item">
          <div class="event_item_dot"></div><div class="event_item_title">15:30</div>
          <div class="event_item_body">Προθεσμία για την υποβολή της πρότασης</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```